# Transit for 19 hours in Istanbul airport, can I go to a hotel

Tags: layovers, uk-citizens, istanbul, ist

I will be in airport turkey for 19 hours en route to Bishkek and Mongolia.  Can I go to a hotel to sleep?

Comment: It's not illegal. What is your specific concern? Visa, timing, money ?

Comment: If you're flying Turkish Airlines, you might be eligible for a free night's stay.

Comment: Usually, over 8 hours for economy and 7 for business class layover time permits a hotel stay. You should ask the staff :)